# Duda sobre PHP $variable['cod']

Tags: php

Tengo una duda en PHP y la pregunta es la siguiente

Por que a una variable se le pase lo siguiente:

```
$variable['cod'] = $pruducto
```

mi pregunta el por que de esto $variable['cod'] que es lo que se le esta pasando a esta variable con cod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el caso que expones, `$variable` sería un array.

El Manual de PHP define los [arrays](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php) así:

> Un array en PHP es en realidad un mapa ordenado. Un mapa es un tipo de
>   datos que asocia *valores* con *claves*.

Hay  más cosas, porque los arrays pueden tener muchos niveles, ser multidimensionales, contener arrays dentro de otros arrays representando estructuras de datos complejas.

Pero la clave de todo está en que un array **asocia *valores* con *claves***.

En tu caso, `cod` es una clave y *podría tener*  o no un valor asociado a esa clave.

- En caso de tenerlo lo que haría `$variable['cod'] = $producto;` sería **cambiar** el valor de esa clave, asignándole `$producto`.
- En caso de no tenerlo lo que haría `$variable['cod'] = $producto;` sería **crear** la clave `cod` en el array, y asignarle el valor de `$producto`.

Veamos un ejemplo:

```
$variable = array(
    "nombre" => "Pedro",
    "cod" => "codXYZ",
);
```

Aquí `$variable` es un array con dos claves: `nombre` y `cod`, cada una de las cuales tiene un valor asociado.

Si tú haces esto:

```
$producto="codABC";
$variable['cod'] = $producto;
```

Lo que haces es cambiar el valor `codXYZ` por el valor `codABC`.

Lo podemos probar con:

```
var_dump($variable);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(2) {
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(5) "Pedro"
  ["cod"]=>
  string(6) "codABC"
}
```

Si pruebas a hacer algo como esto:

```
$producto="codPQR";
$variable['codNuevo'] = $producto;
```

Verás que ahora aparece en el array una nueva clave que se llama `codNuevo`. Dado que esa clave no existía, se crea en el array:

```
var_dump($variable);
```

**Salida:**

```
array(3) {
  ["nombre"]=>
  string(5) "Pedro"
  ["cod"]=>
  string(6) "codABC"
  ["codNuevo"]=>
  string(6) "codPQR"
}
```

### Lectura recomendada

Todo el apartado sobre [arrays en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.types.array.php).

Answer (score 2):

$variable  en este caso es un arreglo y 'cod' es el nombre que le estás dando a una posición dentro de ese arreglo

y tu codigo lo que está haciendo es copiar el valor que tiene $producto a la posición 'cod' dentro de $variable, para que quede claro te recomiendo ejecutes el codigo:

```
$variable['cod'] = $pruducto;
$variable['cod_otro'] = 123;
$variable['otro_cod'] = "ABC";
var_dump($variable);
```

var_dump() Te impimirá la estructura que tienes en $variable y así verás cada elemento del arreglo $variable

Answer (score 1):

Lo que hace esa línea es asignar el valor de $pruducto a la posición con índice "cod" del array $variable.